# Encode and decode hashes for use as database GUID's using Python

Tags: python, database, hash

I'm sure this is common enough use case, but I must have the search terms incorrect.

**Use case:**

- Data is scraped from a variety of sources and has no GUID
- To generate one, I want to encode a few text columns as part of Python pre-processing

  - Ideally, encoded values will be hexadecimal of ~20-30 characters (GUID)
- The encoded values must be trivially decoded back into text as needed

**Input:**

- `.json` object

```json
{
  "guid": "",
  "source": "nytimes",
  "pubDate": "Wed, 15 Dec 2021 20:00:47 +0000",
  "headline": "Fed Expected to Cut Economic Support Faster as Inflation Fears Grow",
  "link": "https://www.nytimes.com/live/2021/12/15/business/inflation-retail-sales-stocks"
}
```

**Tried:**

- Using the Python built in `hash()` method

```py
def create_hash(obj):
  for o in obj:
    hash_object = hash(o['link']) + hash(o['pubDate'])
    o['guid'] = str(hash_object)
  return headline
```

**Output:**

```json
{
  "guid": "-828245169239551952",
  "source": "nytimes",
  "pubDate": "Wed, 15 Dec 2021 20:44:39 +0000",
  "headline": "Fed Expected to Cut Economic Support Faster as Inflation Fears Grow",
  "link": "https://www.nytimes.com/live/2021/12/15/business/inflation-retail-sales-stocks"
}
```

**Problems:**

1. Is the `hash()` function a safe way to avoid database collisions?

   - If so, how is the `hash()` function decoded?
2. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `hash(h['link']) + hash(h['pubDate'])` what's the `h`?

Comment: Sorry. It was a redaction error! Edited.

Comment: There are contradicting requirements here: 1) data should be encoded into 20..30 characters 2) hash should be reversible, i.e. it is possible to restore data from hash. In a general case, if the input data is not restricted to 20..30 characters, that requires indefinitely effective compression algorithm

Comment: `hash` is neither reversible nor collision resistant (can't be used as a primary key). From the spirit of the problem, I'd probably just use canonical URL for this